# How do you get the key that is guarded by the jumping lizard in the "urchin" area?

Tags: botanicula

I'm in the area full of urchin-like things, where a key is guarded by a jumping lizard.
I found the four other keys, but I can't get this one. I tried clicking on the three "urchin-like" plants, in different orders, but I didn't find the solution. Any tips?

I can't post an image here since I'm a new user, but here is the link to the screencap:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Bend the long, red thorn/spine down to the ground so the brown thing hops atop it.** Then release it so the brown thing (temporarily) flings away. Now the green urchin can walk away (upon click), and Mr. Feather can fetch the key.

[image: urchin stage]
[image: gone]

Comment: @musewave If this worked for you, would you be kind enough to mark it as the accepted answer?